# How to cancel draggable in an absolutePanel only for selectInput scroll bar?

Tags: r, shiny

I have many possible choices in a `selectInput`, inside an `absolutePanel`.

I want the `absolutePanel` to be `draggable`.

However, when `draggable = T` the scroll bar for the `selectInput` does not work. When I click on it, it assumes the dragging behavior, instead of scrolling up and down.

Using the "two fingers" on a mousepad laptop, or the scroll in a mouse works, but I need to make that scroll bar useful.

Any ideas?

Reproducible example follows from a [Google Groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/4jQsP1Ul3vQ) that hasn't been answered.

ui

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Leaflet App", id="nav",
                   tabPanel("Interactive map",
                            absolutePanel(id = "controls", fixed = TRUE,
                                              draggable = TRUE, top = 100, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                                              width = 400, height = "auto",
                                              h2("Select Province"),
                                              br(),
                                              uiOutput("state_province_select")
                                )
                            )               
)
)
```

server

```
shinyServer ( 
  function(input, output) {
    output$state_province_select <- renderUI({
      selectchoices <- c("Prince Edward Island","Ontario",
                         "Prince Edward Island1","Ontario1",
                         "Prince Edward Island2","Ontario2",
                         "Prince Edward Island3","Ontario3",
                         "Prince Edward Island4","Ontario4",
                         "Prince Edward Island5","Ontario5",
                         "Prince Edward Island6","Ontario6",
                         "Prince Edward Island7","Ontario7",
                         "Prince Edward Island8","Ontario8")
          selectlabel <- "Province"
          choiceselected <- "Prince Edward Island"
          selectInput("state_province_select",paste("Select ",selectlabel,":"),
                      choices = selectchoices, selected = choiceselected)
        })
      }
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried `fixed=FALSE` ?

Comment: Yes, same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite annoying.

Not really an answer, but an alternative: use `shinyjqui`. Like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- navbarPage("Leaflet App", id="nav",

                 tabPanel("Interactive map",

                          jqui_draggable(
                            div(
                              h2("Select Province"),
                              br(),
                              uiOutput("state_province_select")
                            ),
                            options = list(cancel = ".shiny-input-container")
                          )
                 )               
)
```

Comment: Not an answer, indeed. But, it solves the problem by just wrapping the `absolutePanel` inside the `jqui_draggable`. Easy, neat and fast. Thanks